# Visual-line-mode not working in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, visual-line-mode

I've seen a lot of questions relating to visual-line-mode not working in specific modes, e.g., org mode, but I can't get it to work in spacemacs in text mode. The relevant part of my .spacmacs file:

```
  (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-visual-line-mode)
  (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation-on)
```

The second line is something I found somewhere (this site, probably) to make the cursor movement more natural, but the only line in the configuration file proper that I can find that has something to do with visual line mode is this

```
   dotspacemacs-visual-line-move-text nil
```

and it doesn't look like it actually turns anything on.

I've tried `M-x visual-line-mode`, which (interestingly) first disables it and then enables it, but no matter what I do, the hard line breaks are inserted.

I'd like to use spacemacs for normal writing, but the hard line breaks inserted every 80 chars makes this impossible.